# Smoothing a image while retaining the edges

Tags: image-processing, image

In my previous post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183174/converting-image-into-graphics) it is mentioned that using `ImageResize` before `ImageGraphics` will increase image quality of the final vector image. So now I have another "blurry" image here, which is, a "colored" version of it.

[image]

For this, the simple trick does not work anymore. Using `ImageResize` ends up yielding a equally blurry image. So what can I use to get a smooth but sharp, version of this image? Using `GaussianFilter` will destroy the edges, which is not desired.

Comment: Median filtering is a technique that can be effective at smoothing while preserving edges.  I don't know if you think it is an improvement, but you can try `MedianFilter[img, 1]`